# AssertJ assert on the cause message

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, assertj

Is there a way when using AssertJ agains a method throwing an excetion to check that the message in the cause is equal to some string.

I'm currently doing something like:

```
assertThatThrownBy(() -> SUT.method())
            .isExactlyInstanceOf(IllegalStateException.class)
            .hasRootCauseExactlyInstanceOf(Exception.class);
```

and would like to add an assertion to check the message in the root cause.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### AssertJ 3.23

- [`cause()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.23.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractThrowableAssert.html#cause()) is favored over `getCause()`:

```java
Throwable runtime = new RuntimeException("no way", 
                                         new Exception("you shall not pass"));

assertThat(runtime).cause()
                   .hasMessage("you shall not pass");
```

- [`rootCause()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.23.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractThrowableAssert.html#rootCause()) is favored over `getRootCause()`:

```java
Throwable rootCause = new RuntimeException("go back to the shadow!");
Throwable cause = new Exception("you shall not pass", rootCause);
Throwable runtime = new RuntimeException("no way", cause);

assertThat(runtime).rootCause()
                   .hasMessage("go back to the shadow!");
```

---

#### AssertJ 3.16

Two new options are available:

- [`getCause()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.16.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractThrowableAssert.html#getCause()):

```java
Throwable runtime = new RuntimeException("no way", 
                                         new Exception("you shall not pass"));

assertThat(runtime).getCause()
                   .hasMessage("you shall not pass");
```

- [`getRootCause()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.16.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractThrowableAssert.html#getRootCause()):

```java
Throwable rootCause = new RuntimeException("go back to the shadow!");
Throwable cause = new Exception("you shall not pass", rootCause);
Throwable runtime = new RuntimeException("no way", cause);

assertThat(runtime).getRootCause()
                   .hasMessage("go back to the shadow!");
```

---

#### AssertJ 3.14

[`extracting`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.14.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#extracting(java.util.function.Function,org.assertj.core.api.InstanceOfAssertFactory)) with `InstanceOfAssertFactory` could be used:

```java
Throwable runtime = new RuntimeException("no way", 
                                         new Exception("you shall not pass"));

assertThat(runtime).extracting(Throwable::getCause, as(THROWABLE))
                   .hasMessage("you shall not pass");
```

`as()` is statically imported from `org.assertj.core.api.Assertions` and `THROWABLE` is statically imported from `org.assertj.core.api.InstanceOfAssertFactories`.

Answer (score 15):

Not exactly, the best you can do at the moment is using [`hasStackTraceContaining`](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractThrowableAssert.html#hasStackTraceContaining(java.lang.String)), example

```java
Throwable runtime = new RuntimeException("no way", 
                                         new Exception("you shall not pass"));

assertThat(runtime).hasCauseInstanceOf(Exception.class)
                   .hasStackTraceContaining("no way")
                   .hasStackTraceContaining("you shall not pass");
```

Comment: Consider using `getCause()` if your version is >= 3.16 as suggested by Stefano Cordio